# How to update a user with REST API v2 knowing only the username?

Tags: users, rest-api

I'd like to call WP REST API to update a user.
I have only username, so I suppose I should retrieve user ID first of all, as the endpoint for updating a user is:

```
GET /wp/v2/users/<id>
```

How to retrieve the ID with username (that is unique as well)?

I tried:

```
GET /wp/v2/users/?username=USERNAME
```

but it's not working.

I also tried:

```
GET /wp/v2/users/?slug=USERNAME
```

and it works, but I'm not sure it would not return duplicates.

The best would be update directly the user with a single call, with the username as key, but if this is not possible, I would like to be sure 100% the retrieved ID is the one of the unique username I provided.

Comment: I think there's a bigger architectural problem here that needs to be solved. The question I would ask is: Why do you only have the username? If you need to update users over the API, then you need the ID, so I would suggest reworking your application so that you always have the ID available so that you don't need to make extra requests.

Comment: Is either what @JacobPeattie says or create your own endpoint I guess.

Comment: what about the first request: how to retrieve the ID given the username without ambiguity?

Comment: With the built-in endpoints, you can't. The `users/?slug=` option is the closest.